# Git LFS migration and conf files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm trying to migrate an existing project with multiple branches to use Git LFS.

The doc says "create and commit a file named .lfsconfig at the repository root. This file can specify LFS options the same way as allowed in .git/config"

But what happens to branches which know nothing about this .lfsconfig file or .gitattributes ? Do they use the conf files from master branch ? Do you need to set up some options globally (in your ~/.git) ?

Comment: Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866402/why-does-git-lfs-migrate-not-track-all-pdf-files) help?

Comment: No, should it ? You have the answer to my question ? I mean the "--everything" part is interesting, but I'm not even using "git lfs migrate", I use bfg

Comment: Perhaps you have to explain, why you don't use the same sequence of comands as shown in my question? This worked and it should be generic (from what I understand).

Comment: Did you have multiple branches ? Do u know the answer to my question ?

Comment: I've created an issue on gitlfs github, I think .lfsconfig is just ignored when u are not on the branch where it's created : https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4192

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment. Hopefully, it helps to get things work:

> But what happens to branches which know nothing about this .lfsconfig
> file or .gitattributes?

You don't need to take care of these details. `git lfs` magically does what you need. See below for the process.

> Do they use the conf files from master branch? Do you need to set up some options globally (in your ~/.git) ?

You don't need to change config files.

I just made a test and it works:

```
git init
#add test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "initial"
#change test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "l1"

git checkout -b mybranch
#change test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "mbl1"

git checkout master
#change test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "ml2"

# giving
# * 34fd7dd (HEAD -> master) ml2
# | * d58560f (mybranch) mbl1
# |/
# * de26a14 l1
# * 451129f initial

git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.txt"
git status
# On branch master
# nothing to commit, working tree clean

git lfs ls-files
# b940d77f9e - test.txt

git checkout mybranch
# Switched to branch 'mybranch'
git branch -av
#  master   0c44e15 ml2
# * mybranch 14e031c mbl1
```

`git lfs` created a `.gitattributes` containing

```
*.txt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Comment: Ok, could u just make a sentence in english to answer the question ? which is : "Do branches use the conf files from master branch ? Do you need to set up some options globally (in your ~/.git) ?" Technical demonstration is just a bonus  ;)

Comment: Well, you say "u don't need to change config files" but "git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.txt"" creates a config file. And I need to customize ".lfsconfig" (to change the place where my LFS files are uploaded), that's why I mention ".lfsconfig" in my question.

Comment: @Tristan I don't understand. You state "I'm trying to migrate an existing project with multiple branches to use Git LFS." I think, I showed a way how you can do that.

Comment: Yeah, it's an introduction to give context, and the actual question is right below unedited as you can see. If u don't understand a part of the question, u should ask about it imo.